Locate `should not be called on the main thread` warning message
This is an old project. When I ran it, I output a lot from the console.
This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.

Error message, but in Xcode's Issue Navigator, I don't see anything indicating where this error message comes from?
This is an old project, so I don't want to manually check all the code.


I do not want to say dispatchqueue etc. you already know it i guess. I think the best practice in this situation is Swift 6 and its new generation.

Do you have network calls or other API-calls that are known by Apple to be unresponsive, like HealthKot calls and closures?
